# What do the words בֶּאֱמֶת אָמְרוּ teach us in the Mishna?

Tags: words, hebrew, mishna, language, maseches-shabbos

Mishna [Shabbat 1:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Shabbat.1.3?lang=bi):

> לֹא יֵצֵא הַחַיָּט בְּמַחְטוֹ סָמוּךְ לַחֲשֵׁכָה, שֶׁמָּא יִשְׁכַּח וְיֵצֵא. וְלֹא הַלַּבְלָר בְּקֻלְמוֹסוֹ. וְלֹא יְפַלֶּה אֶת כֵּלָיו, וְלֹא יִקְרָא לְאוֹר הַנֵּר. **בֶּאֱמֶת אָמְרוּ**, הַחַזָּן רוֹאֶה הֵיכָן תִּינוֹקוֹת קוֹרְאִים, אֲבָל הוּא לֹא יִקְרָא. כַּיּוֹצֵא בוֹ, לֹא יֹאכַל הַזָּב עִם הַזָּבָה, מִפְּנֵי הֶרְגֵּל עֲבֵרָה

We generally assume there are no extra words in Mishna. However, it appears the meaning of the above mishna would remain the same if words בֶּאֱמֶת אָמְרוּ were removed. What are these words coming to teach us?

Comment: Maybe see [Bartenura on Terumot 2:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Terumot.2.1?lang=bi&p2=Bartenura_on_Mishnah_Terumot.2.1.2&lang2=bi)? (Found through [Tosafot Yom Tov on Shabbat.1.3](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Shabbat.1.3?lang=bi&p2=Tosafot_Yom_Tov_on_Mishnah_Shabbat.1.3.2&lang2=bi))

Comment: @TamirEvan - does Bartenura mean that these words indicate halachot that are as clear and as undisputed as if it was halacha leMoshe miSinai?

Comment: I don't know, and don't want to err and mislead by stating what little I do know.

Comment: The Rosh in nida may discuss this (10?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Bava Metzia 60a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bava_Metzia.60a.6?lang=bi):

> א"ר אלעזר עדא אמרה כל באמת אמרו הלכה היא
>
> **Rabbi Elazar said: That is to say, every** time a halakha is introduced with the phrase: **Actually they said**, it **is** an established **halakha** with regard to which there is no uncertainty.
>
> *(Steinsaltz **translation** and elucidation)*

Comment: For what it's worth, [Yerushalmi Kilayim 2:1 (6b)](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Jerusalem_Talmud_Kilayim.6b.1) says: "א"ר לעזר כל מקום ששנו באמת הלכה למשה מסיני".

Comment: @TamirEvan why not post that as an answer?

Comment: @JoelK - I guess because the Bartenura on Terumot 2:1 Tamir quoted above says that specifically in Shabbat 1:3 this is not הלכה למשה מסיני, but similar to it.